# apple-touch.png: create size 0 files or handle in nginx?

Tags: web, nginx

I'd like to avoid nginx error messages for missing files like "apple-touch...png", and I see two options:

1. Create an empty file for all the apple-touch....png files in all projects (using a Bash script)
2. Make nginx return an empty file for these files (using an include statement in all virtual servers)

Which of these methods would be preferred, or are there better ways of dealing with these?

Answer (score 1):

if what you're trying is keeping a clean access log, then you could do this

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
}
```

or you can do

```
location ~* apple-touch.png {
    empty_gif;
}
```

this will make nginx serve a `1px x 1px` empty gif file.

---

**EDIT**: using try_files

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
# or location ~* apple-touch.png if you want
   try_files $uri /images/empty.gif;
}
```

if `$uri` doesn't exist it would serve the 2nd image instead `/images/empty.gif` in this example..

Comment: Interesting! How would I serve images when they exist (if some domains have some of them), and just get silence in the logs for whatever doesn't exist?

Comment: well the first one `log_not_found off` means if you don't find the image don't log a 404 in the access log, isn't that what you want?

Comment: You're right, probably :) I'll try it! Two questions: 1) I'll have to add this block to every server definition, right? 2) Could try_files be used for the same purpose?